# Using CkEditor in Rails how do I enable image upload from local file system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

i have a rails application using PaperClip with CKEditor version 3.7.

i would like to enable upload of images from the local file system. i see i can use FCKEditor but all i can see is it's applicable for PHP and ASP.Net.

is that another option or do i need to do custom integration?

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate elfinder into ckeditor.

- http://elfinder.org/
- https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-CKEditor
- https://github.com/phallstrom/el_finder
- https://github.com/phallstrom/el_finder-rails-example

Disclaimer - I wrote the Rails connector.  It's meant for 1.x elfinder, but will work with 2.x using the translater (not everything is supported yet though).  I'm working on pure 2.x support now.

Comment: @RajeshBhatia  When you click the image toolbar button, the 'upload to server' stuff loads elfinder.  file gets uploaded, elfinder passes the url path back to ckeditor.